# Is it possible to upload image to assets folder inside frontend using multer?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, multer

I work on MEAN app and I want to upload image to assets folder in frontend. I am using multer for uploading images. The problem is that i can't upload to angular part but only to backend part of app when i specify destination inside multer.diskStorage().Is it possible to do this or is there some alternative i can transfer all images from backend/uploads to frontend/src/assets or to access that images inside backend from .html in angular (frontend)?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null,"uploads")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage});

app.post("/file",upload.single("file"),(req,res)=>{
    const file = req.file;
    if(file){
        res.json(file)
    }else{
        throw new Error("File upload unsuccessful")
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a good question but also pretty much like a [XY Proplem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please include your actual use case for trying to save images directly into your /src/assets folder. That seems highly unusual.

As far as I know everything from your `src` folder is later bundled through webpack probably into an output folder called `dist` (but depends on your setup). That would mean you can't just add files in production into the `src` folder - you would have to rebuild the website. Adding files to the bundled output folder (e.g. `dist`) probably doesn't work either, but haven't tried that one.

### Serving static files in Express ([docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html))

Your are using `express`, so I guess a far better solution would be to set a static folder and serve the uploaded images as static files. Do this in express like this :

```js
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))
```

This will serve all files inside your `uploads` folder, under a virtual path prefix `/static`. That means you can view the files (=images) inside the browser using

```sh
http://<YOUR-URL>/static/image1.png
http://<YOUR-URL>/static/image2.png
```

---

**About moving the uploaded files into your `src/assets` folder** 
Technically speaking there shouldn't be a problem with that. You could either specify the `src/assets` folder directly inside the `destination` callback of multer or you add a script that moves the file after it's being uploaded. But again, this wouldn't do much - you wouldn't be able to use/see the images in the frontend, not until you rebuild the website (build step with webpack or similiar).

---

**Setup destination callback for `multer`**
If your project folder looks like the following:

```js
/
  server.js
  multer.js
  /src
    /assets
      file1.png
      file2.png
```

You would setup the destination callback for multer like this

```js
// multer.js

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/src/assets') // with leading `/`
  },
  filename: /* ... */
})
```

But this  highly depends on your project folder structure.

Comment: 'You could either specify the src/assets folder directly inside the destination callback of multer'. I also tried like this and it just concatenate frontend/app/src/assets to backend part. is it a way i can put absolute destination, or to make him not putting default prefix to my destination. Thanks

Comment: For the multer part there is a chance you are setting the destination wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: @NikolaCitakovic what do you mean "concatenate to backend part" ? How does your complete project folder structure look like ? Please include it in your question .